# what percent of $.72$ quintal is $2.5 kg$?

Tags: ratio

what percent of $0.72$ quintal is $2.5 kg$?

I am a 8 years old boy from INDIA. Please help me. how do I start have no idea. Tomorrow is my exam please help me.

Comment: Do you mean percent?

Comment: yes.... sorry ...i have edited

Comment: Apparantly, in India, a quintal is 100 kg http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintal

Comment: if i convert 0.72 quintal= 72000 gm. and 2kg 500gm = 2500 gm. then how will i do?

Comment: ^That's a good start. Now, you need to compute (2500 g)/(72000 g) and multiply by 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that a quintal is $100kg$ then $0.72$ quintal is $72kg$ and so $$\frac{2.5}{72} \times 100 = 3.4\% $$ is the answer your are looking for